# Autohotkey script to send space when tapped and shift when held. It is affecting other mappings

Tags: autohotkey

I wrote this script to make my space-bar button act as a space-bar when tapped and a shift button when held. However, it affects mappings such as

> ::btw::by the way

### Scenario:

when I tapped space-bar after typing "btw" to convert "btw" into "by the way ", the conversion did not take place.

---

---

Is there anyway that I can change my script below to ensure that conversion in the above scenario happens?

```
$Space::
now := A_TickCount
while GetKeyState("Space", "P") ; to find out whether space-bar is held 
    if (A_TickCount-now > 180) ; this time is tested on asker's computer
    {
        SendInput {Shift Down}
        KeyWait, Space
        SendInput {Shift Up}
        return
    }
SendInput {Space} ; if key detected to be tapped, send space as per normal
return
```

Thanks :)

Comment: As it should work, I would like to see your entire code that was fixed using my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hotstrings ignore events generate by Autothotkey if their send level is equal or lower than the send level of the event.

This means that the send level of `Space`, must be set to a higher level than the level of hostrings you wish to trigger with it:

```
#InputLevel, 10  ;set send level for the following code to 10
$Space::
#InputLevel  ;set it back to default value of 0 for any remaining code
now := A_TickCount
while GetKeyState("Space", "P") ; to find out whether space-bar is held 
    if (A_TickCount-now > 180) ; this time is tested on asker's computer
    {
        SendInput {Shift Down}
        KeyWait, Space
        SendInput {Shift Up}
        return
    }

SendInput {Space} ; if key detected to be tapped, send space as per normal   
return
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, I tried the code on my computer and it did not work as expected; I still have the same scenario above. Any success for your code on your computer?

Comment: @NeoDingYue Yes, I tested the code beforehand. The hotstring `::btw::by the way` triggered.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the auto-replace code for `btw` to

```
:*:btw::by the way
```

instead of

```
::btw::by the way
```

this will auto-replace `btw` to `by the way` even if you have the mentioned  hotkey for `space`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I have many such other mappings like the auto-replace code above and would still like to have some autonomy over the string to be replaced; like if I want to type for instance "btwer" without having the auto-replace making it hard to do so. It is still an interesting workaround though :)

Answer (score 0):

@Neo Ding Yue Is it working? Initially I did it like you, but it had many flaws. Finally I found a solution which I am using since two years: 1. registry remap space to behave like LShift and use this code:

```
~*LShift::    ;tilde so it gets triggered already on down, in combination with any key, hence can be used as modifier key
Keywait,LShift, L ; just to deactivate autofire
return

~LShift up::
IF(A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 150 && A_PriorKey = "LShift") {
    SendInput {Space}
}
return
```

If you have question, just ask (I have other versions).